# Como recuperar o body e o header de uma transção POST em PHP?

Tags: php, post

Para recuperar o conteúdo `body` de uma transação que recebemos via `POST` usamos a essa função `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Porém existem várias empresas que podem enviar uma requisição post para o nosso serviço e eu preciso saber quem é quem, então certamente deveria verificar o `header`.

Qual a função que deveria usar para recuperar o `body` e o `header` ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe função que ao mesmo tempo faça os dois tem que usar a função [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) (que é um apelido para [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)) e também `file_get_contents('php://input')` e resgatar o `header` e o `body` respectivamente:

***Código:***

```
<?php

    foreach (getallheaders() as $header => $value) {
        echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
    }
```

***Saída:***

```
Content-Type: 
Content-Length: 0 
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36 
Host: localhost 
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
Connection: keep-alive 
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

---

Ou seja a função [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) retorna um `array` da seguinte forma:

```
array(10) {
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(114) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
              AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36"
  ["Host"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["Accept-Language"]=>
  string(35) "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
  ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
  string(23) "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
  ["Connection"]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["Cache-Control"]=>
  string(9) "max-age=0"
}
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)
- [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

Comment: Oi Virgilio, se eu entendi então eu deveria ter no meu arquivo `entryPort.php` (que é a porta de entrada para todas as requisições): `$arrHeader = getallheaders() ...`    em seguida eu recupero o body `$bd=file_get_contents('php://input')` e posso fazer o processamento de acordo com a empresa que me enviou. COrreto?

Comment: Ok já entendi. No meu caso não funcionou pq eu estou usando nginx. Mas na página que vc enviou tem uma função para nginx `http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#84262`